# vim - but with scrolling, clickable text, and copy-paste

Tags: terminal, vim, text-processing, copy-paste, mouse

I like vim.  I think touching mice is dirty.  But sometimes when my hand is already on a mouse, it sure would be nice to be able to scroll the text or click a location in the text and have the cursor jump there.  Also, I wish I could copy and paste with command-c, command-v.  Is there any software out there that answers this desire?  How about for the Mac?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For linux (or at least the Debian family of distributions, e.g Ubuntu) there are the `vim-gnome` and `vim-gtk` packages.

For Mac there is MacVim, for Windows gvim. Both are linked from the [vim download page](http://www.vim.org/download.php).

Comment: oh wow... cool!

Answer (score 13):

On most systems `:set mouse=a` will enable your mouse inside vim even on the console.

I personally prefer using the vim keybindings, but some variant on:

```
:vmap <C-c> "*y
:imap <C-v> <ESC>"*gPa
:nmap <C-v> "*gP
```

Will probably do what you want for ctrl-c and ctrl-v

Comment: Hmm... maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I couldn't get the :set command to work. To experiment, I opened vim to trash.txt, inserted some text, and then pushed <esc>:set mouse=a

Comment: @John you put `set mouse=a` in the file `~/.vimrc`. Read more here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file

Comment: @John If you are on Mac, the default Terminal.app does not support the mouse. Use [iTerm](http://sites.google.com/site/iterm2home/).